# how do I restrict this loop to a particular number?

Tags: php, loops

below is from part of a loop

```
foreach($dataSet as $cType => $cPercentage){ echo $cType ."=". $cPercentage; }
```

this out put datas depend on array. what I want is I want to run this loop to only a particular number of times. say 8 times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$nLoop = 0;
foreach($dataSet as $cType => $cPercentage){
  if ($nLoop++ == 8)
    break;
  echo $cType ."=". $cPercentage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by "to a number", do you mean like "8 times"? That you could do by

```
 $i=0;   
foreach($dataSet as $cType => $cPercentage){
    if($i==8){break;} 
    $i++;
    echo $cType ."=". $cPercentage; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for numeric & associative arrays

```
$count = 0;
foreach($dataSet as $cType => $cPercentage) {
    echo $cType ."=". $cPercentage;
    if (++$count > 8) break;
}
```

Possibly, but not real advantage

```
$cappedArray = array_slice($dataSet, 0, 8, true);
foreach($cappedArray as $cType => $cPercentage) {
    echo $cType ."=". $cPercentage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the for loop to do this for you

Answer (score 0):

Try a while loop

```
$i = 0;
while($ds = each($dataSet) && $i < 8) {
   echo $ds['key']. '='.$ds['value'];
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use another type of loop, e.g. `while`:

```
reset($dataSet);
$i = 8;
while((list($cType, $cPercentage) = each($dataSet)) && $i--) {
    echo $cType, ."=". $cPercentage;
}
reset($dataSet);
```

Reference: [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php), [`each`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php), [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

**Explanation:**

`each` returns the key and value of the item the internal array pointer points to as array and advances the internal pointer. `list` assignes the array of key and value to two variables and returns the array. `$i--` decrements the counter variable.
The loop will stop if either there are no elements in the array anymore (thus the array implicitly returned by `list` will be empty and evaluate to `false`) or if `$i` is `0`.

Comment: @aron n: Yes, this would be instead of using your loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truncate size of array you can use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

so your code would look like this:

```
foreach(array_slice($dataSet, 0, 8) as $cType => $cPercentage){ echo $cType ."=". $cPercentage; }
```